# How to write individual step results in Zephyr(Jira) using ZAPI(REST API)

Tags: jira-rest-api, jira-zephyr

I have looked at the ZAPI documentation, and so far I can get the test cycle id and execution id, so I can execute the test case , write the result for test case in Zephyr. However, I have more test steps in the test case. Now I want to write the results of individual test steps into Zephyr(Jira). Can you please provide sample code for the same(Java preferred). Please a sample code would be helpful.

Approach I have till now: (Found on net)

Get the id's of the stepresults(teststep results) by execution ID using the API "/rest/zapi/latest/stepResult"
Then using these stepresult Id's we can execute them with PUT request using API "/rest/zapi/latest/stepResult/{id}"

version I am currently using:
jira_version:6.3.12
zfj_version:2.5.2
zapi-1.5.0.15001732.obr
Thanks,
Ahmed

Answer (score 1):

First, you need to find a test step execution ID and you will
get step execution ID by execution ID.

You will get execution ID from below:
{{JiraUrl}}/rest/zapi/latest/execution
{
"issueId": 123455,
"versionId": "{versionId}",
"cycleId": "123",
"projectId": {ProjectId}
}

For every issue, there is a different execution ID
Extract a value of "id" from the list of executions corresponding to the issue key.

Now, get step id from below:
/rest/zephyr/latest/stepResult?executionId={id}

Extract a value of "id"

To change the status of a test step, send a PUT request to /rest/zapi/latest/stepResult/{id} with a JSON body specifying the desired status.

{
"status": 3
}

Status | Value =>
-1     |  Unexecuted
, 1     |  Pass
, 2     |  Fail
, 3     |  WIP
, 4     |  Blocked

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the execution and run the navigator ap:
https://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution

https://jira/rest/zapi/latest/execution/navigator/{{execid}}?zql=fixVersion = 'API'&offset=0&maxrecords=0&expand=executionStatus,checksteps&_=1416925447577